# One-way databind gridview - Update only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I'm doing some complicated things with a gridview and the only thing standing between me and completion is the fact that I can't set the databinding programmatically. I've made it most of the way around this issue except that I still cannot get the datasource to update.

I've replaced one input field with a dependent dropdownlist and gotten it to retain the value of the field on databind. I can't databind it directly because I get 'Selected Value not in list of items' or something, so I have to find a way to get the grid or the datasource to take the value from this dependent drop down and apply it to the table.

Any help?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvManager" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ldsCampaigns" 
        ondatabound="gvManager_DataBound" 
        onrowediting="gvManager_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="ContentID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentID" HeaderText="ContentID" 
                SortExpression="ContentID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CampaignName" HeaderText="CampaignName" 
                SortExpression="CampaignName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CampaignTitle" HeaderText="CampaignTitle" 
                SortExpression="CampaignTitle" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CampaignTagLine" HeaderText="CampaignTagLine" 
                SortExpression="CampaignTagLine" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CampaignData" SortExpression="CampaignData">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsTables" 
                        DataTextField="CMSTables" DataValueField="CMSTables" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CampaignData") %>' onload="DropDownList1_Load">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsTables" runat="server" 
                        ContextTypeName="DataContext" 
                        onselecting="ldsTables_Selecting" Select="new (CMSTables)" 
                        TableName="CampaignTables">
                    </asp:LinqDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CampaignData") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DataColumn" 
                SortExpression="DataColumn">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0px" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DataColumn") %>' Visible="False">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("DataColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CampaignLink" HeaderText="CampaignLink" 
                SortExpression="CampaignLink" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunrise" HeaderText="Sunrise" 
                SortExpression="Sunrise" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunset" HeaderText="Sunset" 
                SortExpression="Sunset" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerID" HeaderText="OwnerID" 
                SortExpression="OwnerID" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Enabled" HeaderText="Enabled" 
                SortExpression="Enabled" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you question right, you have a gridview and inside the gridview there is a dropdownlist, on changing the dropdownlist you want to get it's value and fetch some data or whatever you want with it, if that is the case then what you haved is the following:

1-Set your dropdownlist property AutoPostBack = "true".

2-On the dropdownlist_indexchanged event for the dropdownlist do the following:

```
protected void dropdownlist1_indexchanged(sender object,eventargs e)
{
   //Because the dropdownlist is inside the gridview you can't get data directly
   //You will have to parse the sender object which will retrieve the dropdownlist
   DropdownList ddl = (DropdownList)sender;
   //You can then extract the data from the dropdownlist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any future desperate programmer, I had to update the linq data source code on the updated event:

```
    protected void ldsCampaigns_Updated(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DashboardDataContext c = new DashboardDataContext())
        {
            Label Label3 = gvManager.Rows[gvManager.EditIndex].FindControl("Label4") as Label;

            List<CMSCampaigns> change = c.CMSCampaigns.Where(s => s.ContentID == Convert.ToInt16(Label3.Text)).ToList();

            DropDownList DropDownList2 = gvDashboardManager.Rows[gvDashboardManager.EditIndex].FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;


            change[0].DataColumn = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();

            c.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is the clusteriest clusterkludge I've ever kludgestergrammed.